# Twig dynamic creation of variables from string

Tags: templates, dynamic, twig, symfony

I'm using symfony 3 + twig as templating engine.

I need to create variables based on a string, for example I want to

```
{% set varName='Document' %}
```

and then something like

```
{% for createVariable(varName) in entities %}
```

Why this?

Because I have a template A that include another template B.
In template A I set `{% fileToInclude='...' %}` , in template B I include `fileToInclude` that need a specific variable to work, but `fileToInclude` can be another template that needs another specific variable, so I need to create a variable from a string that I set, so if I include for example "document.html.twig" then I'll set varName='Document', and if I include 'news.html.twig', I'll set varName='News'...

How to do that?

EDIT:

FILE A:

```
{% set includeFile='filec.html.twig %} //HERE I can set filed or filee 
{% set varName='document' %}

{% include 'fileb.html.twig' %}
```

FILE B:

```
{% for entity in entities %} // HERE entity should be named document or news or what I need 

{% include includeFile %}

{% endfor %}
```

FILE C:

```
{{ document.title }}
```

FILE D:

```
{{ news.text }}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? Is it that you want to create dynamic variables? If so, I don't see that from your code sample.

Comment: @AlvinBunk edited question

Comment: I till don't undestand your question. Especially '{% for createVariable(varName) in entities %}'

Comment: @Alsatian In order to reproduce something like ' for document in entities' I think in case where varname = 'document'

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 yes, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you want to do, but can't you do something like:

```
{ include('document.html.twig', {varName: 'Document'}) }}
```

or more generic:

```
{ include(data.template, {varName: data.entity}) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is very strange.
But if you want to work with dynamic variable names use that :

```
attribute(_context, varName) {# <- is your variable #}
```